hardhat upgradeProxy can not deploy new contract. implement contract is extreme old contract
When use upgradeProxy in some of chains(Polygon main, Manta etc) some of chains worked. They can upgrade and deploy a new implement contract. But sometimes, when I run upgradeProxy, my new implement contract is extremely old. And just admin contract upgrade and not deploy a new implement contract. I was confused with this. Is there something related with forceImport?
import { ethers, upgrades } from 'hardhat';
async function main() {
const signers = await ethers.getSigners();
const addr = await signers[0].getAddress();
console.log(`deployer address: ${addr}`);

const contract = await ethers.getContractFactory('MyContract');
const deployedProxyAddress = myAddress //eth mainnet
await upgrades.forceImport(deployedProxyAddress, contract)
const sbt = await upgrades.upgradeProxy(deployedProxyAddress, contract);

console.log(await upgrades.erc1967.getImplementationAddress(sbt.address), " getImplementationAddress")
console.log(await upgrades.erc1967.getAdminAddress(sbt.address), " getAdminAddress")


}

main().catch(error => {
console.log(error);
process.exitCode = 1;
})





I deployed two same contracts. And I lose my .openzeppelin/. If I use
forceImport, only one impl in the json file. And one contract upgrade is succeed. How can I make the second one upgrade?

I'm having the same issue, upgrades.upgradeProxy doesn't deploy a new contract, just executes the upgradeAndCall function, and the implementation address doesn't change. I think it should deploy a contract first and then update the implementation address.

Finally, I find the answer, always upgrade the contract.
await upgrades.upgradeProxy(proxyAddress, YourContract, {redeployImplementation: 'always'});

here is the docs for redeployImplementation https://docs.openzeppelin.com/upgrades-plugins/1.x/api-hardhat-upgrades
